# Use and set a default ethernet card for external network/internet (WAN) access

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, usb-device

I'm running an Ubuntu PC with 2 network cards:

- An external USB to ethernet card, `eth1`
- Built in ethernet NIC, `eth0`

I have `eth1` assigned a static IP from the admin and intend to use it as the interface for WAN/internet connectivity. As for `eth0`, it is a workaround for a server with a fixed IP and ethernet address, configured through `/etc/network/interfaces` as shown:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 122.128.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
hwaddress ether 00:10:13:50:a3:77
```

The problem with the above is that even though it does bring up the interface, it is inconsistent and fails to get network connectivity every now and then. `ifconfig` doesn't show any `IPv4` address either! The PC requires a reboot, sometimes multiple times, to get an `IPv4` address.

How can I fix this so that `eth1` is used to get an IPv4 address consistently (as long as the network is not down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading quite a bit on the internet, I came up with the following solution:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 122.128.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
hwaddress ether 00:10:13:50:a3:77
```

What this does is essentially forcing the interface `eth1` to get an `IPv4` address through DHCP explicitly so that the DHCP server knows it is the `eth1` that needs to be mapped.

Comment: Note that "getting an DHCP address" is the default behaviour for most additional software doing networking, like network manager or systemd, so if you need to give them an explicit configuration via `/etc/interfaces`, most likely their default configuration (to be found in different places) screwed things up.

Comment: I learnt it the hard way! So, every interface needs to be explicitly told what to do. Right?

Comment: It depends. In principle it should work without that, but in my experience, in particular network manager tends to screw up in non-standard situations. One would have to debug in detail what actually went wrong to know. If you were doing this the old-fashioned way (without modern programs like network manager or systemd), then yes, you need an explicit DHCP configuration for each interface.

Comment: Will remember that. Point noted. (y)